# Cache issue with static XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a XML file stored in my IIS server. At several stages of the execution, my application retrieves this file. Basically it goes back to the server and gets the file again. The problem is that the application errors out because the file is not returned since it has been cached by the browser. It returns a 304 error. I know that when I pass a changing ID on the URL it is not cached; the problem is that this file has a fixed location and if I put something else in the URL it will not find it. So, is there a way to solve this elegantly? Changing the cache settings on the client is not an option. I use a WebClient object to request the file asynchronously. 
Thanks!

Comment: 304 is not an error.  A lame workaround is to append a random query string value to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

304 is not an error, it is a "not modified" indication according to the HTTP response codes spec. You could try adding a random number or two to the querystring in order to attempt to get a 200 back instead.

Comment: I ended up adding a guid and it works. But I guess you can achive the same with the random function.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the If-Modified-Since header in the request in order to do a conditional GET request. You can then check for the Not Modified (HTTP 304) status code and if it is modified then do something; otherwise let the browser use the cached version.

Here is a blog entry about this technique:
[Setting If-Modified-Since Header in code](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/setting-http-headers-in-net-this-header-must-be-modified-using-the-appropriate-property/)

Answer (score -1):

When you downloaded the XML file the first time, the settings of IIS told the client it was OK to cache the file.  You can [modify the cache settings](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) for the directory containing your XML files so that it will tell the client not to cache anything.

Example:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="myXmlFiles">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      </staticContent>
     </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The poster wants to leverage the cache featuresand find an "elegant" solution to dealing with the HTTP 304 "error".

Comment: That's your reading of the question, it's ambiguous.  My solution solves the problem from the server-side, with no client-side changes required.